# Codepen snippet not working on local machine

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

I modified and copied a snippet from codepen to my local machine. I linked the css and js files with html file. But the css part is not working properly. The code was working fine in codepen.

index.html

```
<head>
  <link src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
<menu class="menu">
  <button class="menu__item active">
     <div class="menu__icon" >
        <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
     </div>
     <strong class="menu__text active">home</strong>
  </button>
  <button class="menu__item">
     <div class="menu__icon" >
        <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
     </div>
     <strong class="menu__text">About</strong>
  </button>
  <button class="menu__item">
     <div class="menu__icon" >
        <i class="fa-solid fa-briefcase"></i>
     </div>
     <strong class="menu__text">
     Products</strong>
  </button>
 <button class="menu__item">
     <div class="menu__icon" >
        <i class="fa-solid fa-question"></i>
     </div>
     <strong class="menu__text">
     Concerns</strong>
  </button>
 
 <button class="menu__item">
     <div class="menu__icon" >
        <i class="fa-solid fa-blog"></i>
     </div>
     <strong class="menu__text">
     Blog</strong>
  </button>
 
  <button class="menu__item">
     <div class="menu__icon" >
        <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
     </div>
     <strong class="menu__text">Contact</strong>
  </button>
</menu>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

styles.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@800&display=swap');
html {
box-sizing: border-box ;
--duration: .45s ;
--cubic: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) ;
--color-1: white ;
--color-2: #000 ;
--theme-bg-color:rgba(16 18 27 / 40%)
--border-color: rgba(113 119 144 / 25%);
 --theme-color: #f9fafb;
}
html *,
html *::before,
html *::after {
box-sizing: inherit ;
}
body {
margin: 0 ;
height: 20vh ;
display: flex ;
overflow: hidden ;
align-items: center ;
justify-content: center ; background: #2193b0; 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);  
background: linear-gradient(to left, #6dd5ed, #2193b0); 
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif ;
}
.menu {
margin: 0 ;
width: 45em;
display: flex ;
height: 5em ;
user-select: none ;
position: relative ;
align-items: center ;
  
    padding: 0 1.7em ;
justify-content: center ;
/* From https://css.glass */
background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.4);
border-radius: 16px;
box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
border-radius: 1em 1em 2.5em 2.5em;
box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
 -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
max-width: 1250px;
 max-height: 860px;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent ;
}
@media (max-width: 42.625em) {
.menu {
font-size: .55em ;
}
}
.menu__item {
all: unset ;
flex-grow: 1 ;
display: flex ;
cursor: pointer ;
overflow: hidden ;
padding-top: 0.5em ;
position: relative ;
align-items: left ;
color: var(--color-1) ;
justify-content: center ;
transition: flex-grow var(--duration) var(--cubic) ;
}
.menu__icon {
font-size: 1.5em;
stroke: currentColor ;
transition: transform var(--duration) var(--cubic) ;
}

.menu__item::after {
left: -1.15em;
bottom: 0 ;
content: " " ;
height: 0.25em ;
position: absolute ;
border-radius: 2em ;
transform-origin: left center ;
background-color: currentColor ;
width: calc( var(--lineWidth) + 5px ) ;
transform: translate3d(3em , 0, 0) scaleX(0) ;
transition: transform calc( var(--duration) + .2s) var(--cubic) ;
}
.menu__text {
left: 4.3em ;
height: 1.5em;
font-size: 1.25em ;
position: absolute ;
text-transform: capitalize ;
letter-spacing: .01em ;
transform: translate3d(0, 109%, 0) ;
transition: transform calc( var(--duration) / 3.7 ) ;
}
.menu__item.active {
flex-grow: 2.3 ;
color: var(--color-2) ;
}
.menu__item.active .menu__icon {
transform: translate3d(-95% , 0, 0) ;
}
.menu__item.active::before {
transform: scale(1) ;
}
.menu__item.active::after {
transform: translate3d(6.3em , 0, 0) scaleX(1) ;
transition: transform var(--duration) var(--cubic) ;
}
.menu__text.active {
transform: translate3d(0 , 0, 0) ;
transition: transform calc(var(--duration) / 1.5) ;
}
.icon {
--duration-icon: 1s ;
fill: none ; 
width: 2.5em ;
height: 2.5em ;
display: block ;
stroke-width: 15 ;
stroke-miterlimit: 10 ;
}
.active #home-anm {
animation: home var(--duration-icon) ;
}
@keyframes home {
25% {
transform: translate3d(0, -.8em , 0) ;
}
50% {
transform: translate3d(0, .5em , 0) ;
}
}
#strategy-anm {
transform: scaleX(.85) ;
transform-origin: center ;
}
.active #strategy-anm {
animation: strategy var(--duration-icon) ;
}
@keyframes strategy {
50% {
transform: scaleX(1) ;
}
100%{
transform: scaleX(.85) ;
}
}
.active #strategy-cir1 {
animation: strategy-cir1 var(--duration-icon);
}
.active #strategy-cir2 {
animation: strategy-cir2 var(--duration-icon) .1s;
}
.active #strategy-cir3 {
animation: strategy-cir3 var(--duration-icon) .2s;
}
@keyframes strategy-cir1 {
50% {
transform: translate3d(-.7em,-0.7em,0);
}
100%{
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
}
@keyframes strategy-cir2 {
35% {
transform: translate3d(0,-0.7em,0);
}
100%{
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
}
@keyframes strategy-cir3 {
35% {
transform: translate3d(.7em,-0.7em,0);
}
100%{
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
}
.active #period-anm {
transform-origin: center 100% ;
animation: period var(--duration-icon) ;
}
.active #period-cir {
transform-origin: center ;
animation: period-cir var(--duration-icon) ;
}
.active #period-line {
stroke-dasharray: 66 ;
animation: period-line calc( var(--duration-icon) / 2.5 ) reverse ;
}
@keyframes period {
35% {
transform: scaleY(.85) ;
}
60% , 70% {
transform: scaleY(1.2) ;
}
100% {
transform: scaleY(1) ;
}
}
@keyframes period-cir {
0%{
opacity: 0 ;
}
35% {
opacity: 1 ;
transform: translate3d(15%, -55%, 0) ;
}
60%{
opacity: 0 ;
transform: translate3d(-8%, -50%, 0) ;
}
}
@keyframes period-line {
100% {
stroke-dashoffset: 66 ;
}
}
.active #security-cir {
transform-box: fill-box ;
transform-origin: center ;
animation: security-cir calc( var(--duration-icon) / 1.5 ) ;
}
@keyframes security-cir {
0% {
transform: scale(0) ;
}
100% {
transform: scale(1) ;
}
}
.active #security-strok {
stroke-dasharray: 96;
animation: security-strok calc( var(--duration-icon) / 1.2 ) ;
}
@keyframes security-strok {
0% {
stroke-dashoffset: 60 ;
}
100% {
stroke-dashoffset: 230 ;
}
}
.active #settings-anm {
transform-box: fill-box ;
transform-origin: center ;
animation: settings-anm calc( var(--duration-icon) / 1.5 ) ;
}
@keyframes settings-anm {
0% {
transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
50% {
transform: rotate(60deg);
}
}
```

index.js

```
/* Intagram: @ui.tormenta*/

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".menu__item");
let activeButton = document.querySelector(".menu__item.active");

buttons.forEach(item => {

    const text = item.querySelector(".menu__text");
    setLineWidth(text, item);

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        setLineWidth(text, item);
    })

    item.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (this.classList.contains("active")) return;

        this.classList.add("active");
        
        if (activeButton) {
            activeButton.classList.remove("active");
            activeButton.querySelector(".menu__text").classList.remove("active");
        }
        
        handleTransition(this, text);
        activeButton = this;

    });

    
});


function setLineWidth(text, item) {
    const lineWidth = text.offsetWidth + "px";
    item.style.setProperty("--lineWidth", lineWidth);
}

function handleTransition(item, text) {

    item.addEventListener("transitionend", (e) => {

        if (e.propertyName != "flex-grow" || 
        !item.classList.contains("active")) return;

        text.classList.add("active");
        
    });

}
```

I put those css and js files in the same folder. When I open the html file, it doesn't show any font-awesome icons or any text, but it shows the navbar layout. I am a complete beginner and any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like this code uses [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/start) icons but you haven't imported them anywhere. The Codepen snippet you used probably has the import in its settings.

Comment: And you're opening the html file in your browser by loading it from a localhost URL using an HTTP server, rather than loading the file directly? As for figuring out what's wrong: open your dev tools, and look at the console, as well as the network tab. There should be plenty of warnings and errors.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the directory path of the CSS link to "folder-name/styles.css" worked for me.

Using './' means the file your looking for exists in the you current directory. I am not sure why the JavaScript worked but to target a file in a folder located in your active directory you should use 'folder/file.txt'

As for the Font Awesome it doesn't look like you have imported it. Go to the below link to see your Font Awesome kits and link one in your HTML file

https://fontawesome.com/kits

Comment: Thanks a lot. Importing Font-Awesome kits solved the problem for me. I did not know that I have to explicitly import that.